# How to set page size for Postscript output file in Adobe InDesign CS5?

Tags: adobe-indesign, export, cs5

I want to **export a document to a postscript file** in InDesign CS5. **How can I set the page size for the document?** Sadly, the option is disabled in my preferences window.

Here is a screenshot of a Russian copy of a program:
[image: screenshot]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Change the PPD file!
When you print to a PostScript printer, PostScript file, or PDF, Indesign automatically uses the default PPD (PostScript Printer Description) for that device. You must switch to a different one to suit your needs.

Choose File > Print.
From the PPD menu, select one of the following:
A PPD that corresponds to the current output device.

Other. Lets you select a custom PPD, such as one provided by your service bureau for use with the specified printer. The PPD’s filename corresponds to the printer’s or imagesetter’s name and model, and may display a .ppd file extension (depending on how your system is set up.) Navigate to the PPD you want, select it, and click Open.

Note: Certain PPD features commonly found in imagesetter PPDs aren’t accessible from the Indesign Print dialog box. To set those printer-specific features, click Setup (Windows) or Printer (Mac OS) in the Print dialog box.